# Trying to animate division of cell in mitosis sim

Tags: javascript, arrays, animation, simulation

I am making a mitosis simulator and I want it to run the mitosis function when the cell is big enough and split. When it splits I want it to animate the split from the initial x value (x of previous cell) to a new x value (x+10 to the right). I've tried used loops and setTimeout() to see if I could delay adding the x to try to animate it, but I can't seem to get that to work. I've never worked with animating before in JS so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Mitosis</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script>
        let c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        let cells = [];
        cells.push(new Cell(100,100,5));
        function Cell(x,y,r) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.r = r;
        }
        function update() {

            move();

            draw();
            if(cells.length < 50) {
                grow();
            }
        }
        setInterval(update,100);
        function draw() {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500)
            for(let i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(cells[i].x,cells[i].y,cells[i].r,0,2*Math.PI);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
        function move() {
            for(let i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {

                cells[i].x += Math.random()*3;
                cells[i].x -= Math.random()*2;
                cells[i].y += Math.random()*3;
                cells[i].y -= Math.random()*2;
            }
        }
        function grow() {
            for(let i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
                if(cells[i].r > 10){
                    mitosis();
                }
                else {
                    cells[i].r+=0.25;
                }
            }
        }
        function mitosis() {
            for(let i = cells.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                cells.push(new Cell(cells[i].x,cells[i].y,5))
                cells.push(new Cell(cells[i].x,cells[i].y,5))
                cells.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, when your big cell is about to divide, you could create and display a list of "snapshots" that show the movement of the two new cells to their new positions before they start growing again.

In that case, if you want to / are allowed to use ES2017 features, this is a possible solution that uses a real sleep -pauses the execution-, rather than timeouts. (I leave it to you to create your snapshot list and the `displaySnapshot` function, which erases and draws each snapshot. It's almost trivial)

```
  function sleep(ms) {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
  async function displaySnapshots(snapshots, timeLapse) {
     for (let snap of snapshots) {
        displaySnapshot(snap);
        await sleep(timeLapse);
     }
 }
```

But not sure if you want to do something like this instead (I think not):

```
     function sleep(ms) {
         return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      }

      async function evolve(timeLapse, iterations) {
         for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            update();
            await sleep(timeLapse);
         }
     }
     evolve(500, 100);
```

Comment: Ive never used es2017 before. Could you possibly point me to a good tutorial of it? That'd be very appreciated.

Comment: @Bestlogo56 that's just the latest specification of the javascript language. Async and await are features in it. It has good support among the most commonly used browsers nowadays.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bestlogo56 no problem, in my opinion the advantage of using a true "sleep" like I suggested is that it makes it easier to reason about your code: whenever you need to pause execution for the animation effect it's just a matter of inserting one line "await sleep(ms)" otherwise what you would have is a nested timeout, one for the mitosis division and one for the cell movement. It's still feasible but it complicates logic. Let me know if you made it work...

Comment: Haven't been able to work on it quite yet, but when I do I'll let you know. Thanks again for the help.